# I want to query for vendors in a certain location and if there is no vendor in that location i want it to return all the vendors in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**I want to query for vendors in a certain location and if there is no vendor in that location i want it to return all the vendors in the database**

````
        Vendor.find({location: req.params.location}, {
            vendorpassword: 0
        }, function (err, vendor) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json({
                    error: 'An error occurred'
                });
            } else if (!vendor) {
                Vendor.find({},{
                    vendorpassword: 0
                },
                function (err, vendor) {
                        res.status(400).json({
                            vendor
                        })});
                
            } else {
                res.status(200).json({
                    vendor
                })
            }
        })
    },```
````

Comment: Ok, if there's no vendor you can simply do a db.collection.find() with no parameters to return all the records on your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should do it

```
Vendor.find({ location: req.params.location }, {
        vendorpassword: 0
    }, (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
            //Manage error
        } else if (response.length < 1 || response == undefined) {
            //Manage what to do if there is no vendors in that location. Making an Vendors.find() should be enough. But is in your hands what to do with that array
        } else if (response) {
            //Manage what to do if there IS vendors in that location
        }
});
```